# Android - Quick Debugging

Tags: android, debugging

What is the best way to "quickly" debug on Android?

While doing web dev, usually I just use *alert()* to quickly get the value of a variable. Is there an analogous operation in Android?

Comment: Breakpoints. If you have a good IDE, it's all integrated. No filtering for the logs you want, just set a break-point and check the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This highly depends on the situation

If I just want a quick message to know that I made it to some point in my `Activity` then I may just use a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) to display a message when my `Activity` was created or that a certain event happened. You can also use [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) messages to view in your logcat to see certain variables and other messages.

Besides that, if you need to do more thorough debugging such as seeing exactly what is happening inside a certain function, then you can set a breakpoint at whichever line(s) you suspect are trouble and check variable/data values in the "Variables" or "Expressions" tabs in your debugger

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Log` class.  Just call `Log.d("Some Tag", Message);`

You can also set breakpoints in your code.  This will let you stop execution of your app at that point and inspect the state of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using these methods to prevent logs from being printed when in not in dev stage, and show the message in a toast when able to:

```
    public static void log(Object message) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.v(TAG, message.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void log(Context context, Exception e) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            if (context != null)
                Toast.makeText(context, e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public static void log(Context context, Object message) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.v(TAG, message.toString());

        if (context != null)
            Toast.makeText(context, message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Or use the debug mode, where you can view detailed info on your variables.